# Turn on/ off your Raspberry Pi3

Tags: pi-3, berryboot

I have a RaspBerry Pi3 with a WD PiDrive attached and the following installed via BerryBoot

Ubuntu Server
LibreELEC

When I shutdown the pi i usually unplug it( I know i don't have to but I think its best at times) and plug it back in to start/ restart it

But how can I turn it on/ off ( remotely) and boot back into Boot Loader so I can choose which OS to boot up?

WoL? It means having to keep it plugged in. Not a problem but I want to be able to atleast get into the boot loader to pick OS

UPDATE

Found this article https://scribles.net/adding-power-switch-on-raspberry-pi/

will let you know how it turns out

Comment: Can you log in from a different computer with SSH?

Comment: @Fabian yes I can but obviously not when its off. Found this article so will see how it goes https://scribles.net/adding-power-switch-on-raspberry-pi/